# How to use the pipe operator as part of a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the url within strings like

```
u1 = "Check this out http://www.cnn.com/stuff lol"
u2 = "see http://www.cnn.com/stuff2"
u3 = "http://www.espn.com/stuff3 is interesting"
```

Something like the following works, but it's cumbersome because I have to repeat the whole pattern

```
re.findall("[^ ]*.cnn.[^ ]*|[^ ]*.espn.[^ ]*", u1)
```

Particularly, in my real code I wanted to match a much larger number of web sites. Ideally I can do something similar to

```
re.findall("[^ ]*.cnn|espn.[^ ]*", u1)
```

but of course it doesn't work now because I am not specifying the web site name correctly. How can this be done better? Thanks.

Comment: note that with the current pattern you have, this produces a match: `re.findall("[^ ]*.cnn.[^ ]*|[^ ]*.espn.[^ ]*", 'abc.espnw.abc')` because dot matches all characters. You need to escape the dot: `re.findall("[^ ]*\.cnn\.[^ ]*|[^ ]*\.espn\.[^ ]*", 'abc.espnw.abc')`

Comment: thanks, sometimes I am not very careful...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non-capturing groups allow you to group characters without having that group also be returned as a match.

`cnn|espn` becomes `(?:cnn|espn)`:

```
re.findall("[^ ]*\.(?:cnn|espn)\.[^ ]*", u1)
```

Also note that `.` is a regex special character (it will match any character except newline). To match the `.` character itself, you must escape it with `\`.

Comment: I call those “non-grouping parentheses”; the word “matches” is just confusing given that REs use that in a different sense too.

Comment: All instances of `.` in your answer should be escaped, otherwise it will match anything that has `espn` or `cnn` in it, such as `Last night on cnn there was`, which is not a desired match.